# Most common sublist in python list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have this list:

```
big_list = [['UPPER', 'UPPER', 'UPPER', 'LEI', 'DATE', 'ISIN', 'DEVISE', 'QUANTITY', 'QUANTITY', 'PRICE', 'MIC'], 
            ['UPPER', 'UPPER', 'UPPER', 'LEI', 'DATE', 'ISIN', 'DEVISE', 'QUANTITY', 'QUANTITY', 'PRICE', 'MIC'], 
            ['UPPER', 'UPPER', 'UPPER', 'LEI', 'DATE', 'ISIN', 'DEVISE', 'QUANTITY', 'QUANTITY', 'PRICE', 'MIC'], 
            ['DEVISE'], 
            ['DEVISE'], 
            ['BORING', 'QUANTITY', 'QUANTITY'], 
            ['BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'UPPER', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING'], 
            ['BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'DEVISE', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'DEVISE', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING'], 
            ['BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING', 'BORING']]
```

And I would like to find out the most common list in my `big_list`.
In this example, the function would give me:
`['UPPER', 'UPPER', 'UPPER', 'LEI', 'DATE', 'ISIN', 'DEVISE', 'QUANTITY', 'QUANTITY', 'PRICE', 'MIC']` which appears 3 times in `big_list` if I may.

What is the shortest and most efficient way to do this ?

I tried to do it with `collections.Counter()` without success.

Thanks

Comment: `Counter(d for d in big_list).most_common(1)[0]` -> `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @zakk8889 that's good information to edit into the original question, not just have as a comment

Comment: oh yeah, but I find only answers that 'consolidates' the sublists in between then, like here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/133159/most-common-elements-of-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're almost there!

```
Counter(tuple(d) for d in big_list).most_common(1)[0] 
(('UPPER', 'UPPER', 'UPPER', 'LEI', 'DATE', 'ISIN', 'DEVISE', 'QUANTITY', 'QUANTITY', 'PRICE', 'MIC'), 3)
```

You need to make your list a hashable type, in this case a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).